# Write a link that does not get converted to an <a/> tag in a markdownified string with hugo

Tags: markdown, hugo

I have a text in my hugo config file, which gets markdownified in the html template. Inside this text I want to have a link but for legal reasons I do not want to convert this link to a "clickable" link. But if I just write

```
Some text http://example.com some more text
```

markdownify converts this link to an `<a/>` tag making it clickable.

Can I prevent this but still use markdownify on the text? The link should still be copy-pastable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an excerpt from my `config.toml` (which sits in the root folder):

```
  testme = "This **link** is not linking to url at all"
```

I address this custom field anywhere, for example, in my `head` partial:

```
{{ replace (.Site.Params.testme | markdownify) "url" "https://codeandsend.com" | safeHTML }}
```

Here's what it does:

1. `{{ .Site.Params.testme | markdownify }}` pipes `testme` value from `config.toml` into the [`markdownify`](http://gohugo.io/templates/functions/#markdownify) function.
2. I then replace all occurencies of string `url` with desired address. You could use any other placeholder instead of `url`, but beware of system-reserved names.
3. `| safeHTML` pipes the result into HTML entities decoder. There's no such thing in Hugo as instruction to *skip* entity encoding — only to decode *post factum*, and `safeHTML` does this.

Result: **bold** text using markdown and no link encoding:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found [this gist](https://gist.github.com/alexpeattie/4729247) with different ways to prevent auto-linking.

**Method 1: Add HTML tags in the hyperlink text**

```
Some text http://<span></span>example.com some more text
```

returns:

> Some text http://example.com some more text

**Method 2: Escape a character from the hyperlink text**
(works with Hugo 0.51 but not with Github)

```
Some text http\://example.com some more text
```

returns:

> Some text http://example.com some more text

(I should note that those are still tricks/hacks since there is no official way to disable auto-linking in markdownify.)